# facet.limit on Solrj v6.1.0

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying increase the amount of term facets returned from a query.

I have first added -1 to the request handler in solrconfig.xml. It works fine if I query solr servers directly, but once I try to use the same query on Solrj client, it is still returns only 10 facets in the response. I have tried to add facet.limit param to the query explicitly for solrj, but still I am only seeing 10 facets in the response. Are there any kind of other params or configs needed for solrj to use unlimited amount of facets or increase the number of facets to something bigger than the default value?

p.s I have initially tried to post the question on the mail list of Solr, but for some reason it failed constantly to post there

edit: I have tried to use direct solr querying with the json.facets, and setting facet.limit value does not work work json.facets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was basically the json.facet part. Although the docs on https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/json-facet-api.html are for 7.2, the same rule applies for 6.1.0.

It is seriously confusing though, as setting the facet.limit value via solrconfig.xml or Solrj client fails silently and there docs do not mention about the issue for json.facets

Comment: Just to be clear - when you set those parameters either in solrconfig.xml or solrj, they're set as regular request parameters. `?facet.limit-1`. The JSON API is a different API, and supports far more detailed settings like a limit per level, etc.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, you are right, and that was the point i was initially missing while testing the solrj client